# Getting dynamic value from database to Rails views

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Hi all I'm working on a ROR app where in an external source modifies our database dynamically. I need to read values from database on the fly and set it in the `value` attribute of `progress` tag of html. But it reads only once and shows the progress bar. If i put a loop around the progress tag, it shows numerous progress bars!! **How can we write the code such that it polls DB in certain intervals, gets required data and moves Progress bar ???**

Below is the code snippet... The value attribute now shows the first/current value of `no_of_tc` at the time of submit. Can we write a `loop` with pause for 10 secs and poll db???

**Controller:**

```
def list
    @user_id = self.current_user.id
    @files = ExcelFile.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ? AND excel_filename IS NOT NULL", @user_id])
   ----SOME CODE---
end
```

**View(list.html.erb):**

```
---code(along with ajax which calls 'waitid' element on OnLoading function)--

<span id='waitid' style="display:none;" class='text'>
           <progress value='<%= @files[4].no_of_tc %>' max="100"></progress>
  </span>
```

Comment: instead of making your ajax call `onLoad`, why not try calling it every x seconds?

Comment: But are there any functions in AJAX to do it like that?? If you have any links regarding this, please help..

Comment: I highly suggest you check this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes). It explains exactly what you need: frequent polling for changes in your DB ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I followed that tutorial and did some changes specific to my app and it WORKS!!

I removed AJAX from this page.. and I'm triggering all changes thru JS/Jquery